# how to change gmap3 codes to leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to change this code to work with leaflet.

I'm using WordPress and dont know how to do that. someone can help me to code this gmap3 to leaflet.

i have set div as `st_google_map_user`

```
jQuery(function($) {
    if ($(".st_google_map_user").length > 0) {
        var data_map = $(".st_user_overview").data("overview");
        console.log(data_map);
        var map = $('.st_google_map_user').gmap3({
            map: {
                options: {
                    zoom: 5
                }
            }
        });
        var gmap_object = map.gmap3('get');
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var markers = [];
        for (var key in data_map) {
            var tmp_data = data_map[key];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(tmp_data[0], tmp_data[1]);
            bounds.extend(myLatLng);
            var marker = ST_addMarker(myLatLng, gmap_object, tmp_data, map)
            markers.push(marker)
        }

        function ST_addMarker(location, gmap_object, tmp_data, map) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                options: {
                    icon: tmp_data[2],
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                },
                data: tmp_data
            });
            return marker
        }
        new MarkerClusterer(gmap_object, markers, {
            gridSize: 50
        });
        gmap_object.fitBounds(bounds)
    }
})
```

I am using a wordpress theme, and theme collects the data about lat, lng.
If someone can describe this code to me, I'm happy and great full with best regards and thanks.

Comment: Please can you show the Leaflet JavaScript that you have tried so far and explain specifically where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Yes, this is library i want use https://leafletjs.com/ , that code is theme default codes using google map library (gmap3) and i want change that to use leaflet library and streetmap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So other users can help you you should upload the JavaScript code you have tried already so we can see where you are getting stuck with Leaflet.